# Control the individual brightness of LEDs on WS2812B

Tags: electrical

I currently have two 16.4Ft WS2812B (individually programmable)  LED strips in my living room, both are connected with a single dataline but 5v DC sources going into it at both ends to prevent voltage drop.

Current setup works great at lower brightness but when running it at max brightness for any color (say white) you can notice the voltage drop as the LEDs are bright at the start of the strip (closer to the 5V source) then they are at the join point.

Now I have some noise going into the dataline (that is my fault) but random LED's start to populate random colors with **differing brightness**. Now I know how to fix this issue but the ability to see that LEDs can be differing brightness really interested me.

***My question is, using the RPI python library I currently have, is it possible to address the brightness of each LED?***

I currently use https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x to control the LED's via multiple python scripts and a Flask webserver.

Any advice on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. The subject of your question is not well suited to the Home Improvement Stack. Since you are working with a rPi board you should take this over to the Raspberry Pi Stack. Here is a link to their [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided an equipment list and vendors so that others can reproduce the exercise: especially if they already have the equipment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this falls into the category of a "hobby project" and is not related to home improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WS2812B LEDs you supply the binary values for Red, Green and Blue of each LED. Each time a new serial bit stream is sent to the LED string all of these values need to be provided. I really suggest that you read the data sheet for the LED and you would already know this.

It is possible to scale the RGB value for each LED by multiplying each of the three LED binary values for the Red, Green and Blue by the factor. To brighten use a factor > 1.0 and to dim use a factor < 1.0. You must use care to make sure that the resulting calculations stay within the size/range of the normal binary values for each color. For example you cannot program a color value > 255 or less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your literal question is really off-topic for the DIY stack...

... But your actual problem is on-topic.   You need a *lot* more feeder.  A *lot*.

Voltage drop is proportional to current (amps), or in effect, proportional to power (watts) squared. When you brighten up the LEDs you are drawing more current and greatly exacerbating the voltage drop problem, which is causing the at-LED controllers to malfunction, and/or leaving too little voltage for the LEDs to operate properly.

Right off the bat you should parallel some beefy wire and tie it in at the "Join" point, so *each* 5m run is powered from both ends.  Then also, you should feed it mid-run in 1-2 places. You can feed it anywhere it's legal to cut it.

You seem to be eager to "just live with" the voltage drop problem, but the electronics in the strip are *not* living with it, and that is why you are having problems.